# is possible to define shortcut in `\tikzset`?

Tags: tikz-styles

i like to define `\tikzset` for bunch of images, in which i define building blocks for control schemes. in defining those block i extensively use `path picture` where for anchors i use `path picture bounding box`. for shorter code i like for it define the shortcut `ppbb`. this is simple to achieve with

```
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}
```

in document preamble. Unfortunately it can't be included in `tikset`. is there some way fir defining shortcuts as part of `\tikzest?

as example of use of the `\ppbb` see [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395589/drawing-a-control-system-with-tikz/395620?noredirect=1#comment984029_395620).

Comment: Isn't `\pgfkeysalsofrom{\ppbb}` meant for such things?

Comment: i dont know, i'm not familar with`pgfkeys`. can you explain this?

Comment: what is the context where tikzset causes problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is entirely personal preference, but considering the use in the linked answer, I wouldn't directly use a macro, I'd use a node alias (which I concede is using a bunch of macros 'under the covers'). Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{alias path picture bounding box/.code=%
  \pgfnodealias{#1}{path picture bounding box}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [fill=red, path picture={%
  \tikzset{alias path picture bounding box=@}
  \fill [orange] (@.north) -- (@.east) -- (@.south) -- (@.west) -- cycle;
}] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]