# Draw a Hasse diagram with circles with 3 sectors

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circles

[image]

Hello everybody,

I am try to draw the Hasse diagram (picture above) but I don't know.

Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [gray] (90:2) arc[start angle=90, end angle =210, radius=2cm] -- (0,0) -- cycle;
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm) (90:2)--(0,0) (210:2)--(0,0) (330:2)--(0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [gray] (210:2) arc[start angle=210, end angle =330, radius=2cm] -- (0,0) -- cycle;
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm) (90:2)--(0,0) (210:2)--(0,0) (330:2)--(0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [gray] (330:2) arc[start angle=-30, end angle =90, radius=2cm] -- (0,0) -- cycle;
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm) (90:2)--(0,0) (210:2)--(0,0) (330:2)--(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [gray] (90:2) arc[start angle=90, end angle =210, radius=2cm] -- (0,0) -- cycle;
  \fill [gray] (210:2) arc[start angle=210, end angle =330, radius=2cm] -- (0,0) -- cycle;
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm) (90:2)--(0,0) (210:2)--(0,0) (330:2)--(0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [gray] (90:2) arc[start angle=90, end angle =210, radius=2cm] -- (0,0) -- cycle;
  \fill [gray] (330:2) arc[start angle=-30, end angle =90, radius=2cm] -- (0,0) -- cycle;
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm) (90:2)--(0,0) (210:2)--(0,0) (330:2)--(0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [gray] (210:2) arc[start angle=210, end angle =330, radius=2cm] -- (0,0) -- cycle;
  \fill [gray] (330:2) arc[start angle=-30, end angle =90, radius=2cm] -- (0,0) -- cycle;
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm) (90:2)--(0,0) (210:2)--(0,0) (330:2)--(0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [gray] (90:2) arc[start angle=90, end angle =210, radius=2cm] -- (0,0) -- cycle;
  \fill [gray] (210:2) arc[start angle=210, end angle =330, radius=2cm] -- (0,0) -- cycle;
  \fill [gray] (330:2) arc[start angle=-30, end angle =90, radius=2cm] -- (0,0) -- cycle;
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm) (90:2)--(0,0) (210:2)--(0,0) (330:2)--(0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

I'm sure you'll get some help with your TikZ, but while you are waiting, here is an alternative approach using [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).  I've wrapped this up in `luamplib` so you should compile it with `lualatex` or work out how to adapt it for plain MP or `pdflatex` + [GMP](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gmp?lang=en).

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    % some points
    x1 = x3 = x6 = 0; -x2 = -x5 = x4 = x7 = 80;
    y2 = y3 = y4 = 0;
    -y1 = y5 = y6 = y7 = 80;

    % connect the dots
    draw z1 -- z2 -- z5 -- z3 -- z7 -- z4 -- cycle;
    draw z1 -- z3;
    draw z2 -- z6 -- z4;

    % routine to make a labelled node
    vardef node(expr description, state) = 
        save p, c; 
        path c; c = fullcircle scaled 42;
        picture p; p = image(
            unfill c;
            for i=-6 upto 6: draw (left--right) scaled 30 shifted (0,3i); endfor
            clip currentpicture to c;
            for i=1 upto 3:
                if substring(i-1,i) of state = "0":
                    unfill origin -- subpath((6+8(i-1))/3,(6+8i)/3) of c -- cycle;
                fi
            endfor
            for i=1 upto 3:
                draw origin -- point (6+8i)/3 of c withpen pencircle scaled 3/4;
            endfor
            draw c withpen pencircle scaled 1;
            label.lrt(description, point 6.25 of c);
        );
        p
    enddef;

    % mark each node ...
    draw node("$T_1$", "111") shifted z1;
    draw node("$T_2$", "110") shifted z2;
    draw node("$T_3$", "101") shifted z3;
    draw node("$T_4$", "011") shifted z4;
    draw node("$T_5$", "100") shifted z5;
    draw node("$T_6$", "010") shifted z6;
    draw node("$T_7$", "001") shifted z7;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use a circular node with a `path picture` to draw and fill the sectors. I made a style that takes two arguments, for the start angle and the number of sectors to cover.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % modify the node distance to set the separation between circles
  node distance=2cm,
  hasse/.style 2 args={
     CircleRad/.store in=\CircRad,
     % change CircleRad to modify radius of circles
     CircleRad=1cm,
     circle,
     draw,
     thick,
     minimum size=2*\CircRad,
     path picture={
        \pgfnodealias{BB}{path picture bounding box} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395641
        \fill [pattern=horizontal lines] (BB.center) -- ++(#1:\CircRad) arc[radius=\CircRad,start angle=#1,delta angle=#2*120] -- cycle;
        \draw (BB.center) -- (BB.90)
              (BB.center) -- (BB.210)
              (BB.center) -- (BB.330);
     },
    node contents={}
  }
]
% first argument to hasse style is the start angle of the filled sector
% second argument is number of sectors to cover
\node [hasse={0}{3}, name=h1];

\node [hasse={330}{2}, name=h3, above=of h1];
\node [hasse={90}{2},  name=h2, left=of h3];
\node [hasse={210}{2}, name=h4, right=of h3];

\node [hasse={90}{1},  name=h6, above=of h3];
\node [hasse={210}{1}, name=h5, left=of h6];
\node [hasse={330}{1}, name=h7, right=of h6];

% draw connections
\foreach \x/\y in {1/2,1/3,1/4,2/5,2/6,3/5,3/7,4/6,4/7}
   \draw (h\x) -- (h\y);

% add labels below circles
\foreach \h in {1,...,7}
  \node [below=1mm,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\footnotesize] at (h\h.south) {$T_{\h}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @PRS No worries. Hard to say what you changed though ...

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It looks like T5 and T6 are exchanged.

Comment: @Kpym Ah, right, that could what the OP was referring to above.

Answer (score 4):

A `pstricks` solution.  based on the `xstring` package, I define a`\ThreeSectors`command, with an optional argument (one of `W, S,E, SW, SE, WE`) which decides which sector(s) are hatched.

```
\documentclass[old, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-poly, pst-eucl}%, auto-pst-pdf
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand\ThreeSectors[1][]{%
\PstTriangle[PolyName=A, linestyle=none]%\pscircle
\pstCircleOA{A0}{A1}
\psline(A2)(A0)(A1)(A0)(A3)
{\psset{fillstyle = hlines, hatchwidth = 0.5pt, hatchsep = 1.5pt, hatchcolor = LightSlateGray!80, hatchangle = 0}%
\IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
{S}{\pscustom{\psline(A0)(A2)\pstArcOAB{A0}{A2}{A3}\psline(A3)(A0)}}
{W}{\pscustom[hatchangle = 60]{\psline(A0)(A1)\pstArcOAB{A0}{A1}{A2}\psline(A2)(A0)}}
{E}{\pscustom[hatchangle =-60]{\psline(A0)(A1)\pstArcnOAB{A0}{A1}{A3}\psline(A3)(A0)}}
{SE}{\pscustom[hatchangle = 60]{\psline(A0)(A1)\pstArcnOAB{A0}{A1}{A2}\psline(A2)(A0)}}
{SW}{\pscustom[hatchangle = -60]{\psline(A0)(A1)\pstArcOAB{A0}{A1}{A3}\psline(A3)(A0)}}
{WE}{\pscustom{\psline(A0)(A3)\pstArcOAB{A0}{A3}{A2}\psline(A2)(A0)}}}%
[{\pstCircleOA*{A0}{A1}}] }%
\psline(A1)(A0)(A2)(A0)(A3)}%

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=1.2cm, unit = 0.6]
    %% nodes
    \ThreeSectors[W] &\ThreeSectors[S] &\ThreeSectors[E] \\
    \ThreeSectors[SW] &\ThreeSectors[WE] &\ThreeSectors[SE] \\
    & \ThreeSectors
    %%arrows \\
    \psset{arrows=-, arrowinset=0.15, nodesep=-0.4pt, linewidth=0.6pt, npos = 0.3,labelsep = 8pt}
    \ncline{1,1}{2,1}\ncput*{T₅} \ncline{1,1}{2,2}
    \ncline{1,2}{2,1}\ncline{1,2}{2,3}
    \nput[labelsep = 8pt]{-90}{1,2}{T₆}
    \ncline{1,3}{2,2}\ncline{1,3}{2,3}\ncput*{T₇}
    \ncline{2,1}{3,2}\ncline{2,2}{3,2}\ncput*{T₃}\ncline[nodesepB = -0.5pt]{2,3}{3,2}
    \nput{-90}{2,1}{T₂} \nput{-90}{2,3}{T₄}
    \nput{-90}{3,2}{T₁}
  \end{psmatrix} \] %

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @PRS: I was out of my mind, I guess. 'Tis fixed.

Answer (score 1):

And one more tikz code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[1/.style={fill=lightgray},0/.style={fill=white}]
    \foreach \a/\b/\c/\y/\x/\n in {1/1/1/0/1/1, 1/0/1/1/0/2, 0/1/1/1/1/3, 1/1/0/1/2/4, 0/0/1/2/0/5, 1/0/0/2/1/6, 0/1/0/2/2/7}{
      \begin{scope}[shift={([scale=3]\x,\y)}]
        \path coordinate (T\n) (0,-1.3) node[fill=white]{$T_\n$};
        \foreach[count=\i] \s in {\a,\b,\c}{
          \draw[rotate=90+\i*120,\s,thick] (0,0) -- (0:1) arc(0:120:1) -- cycle;
        }
      \end{scope}
    }
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \foreach \s/\t in {1/2,1/3,1/4,2/5,2/6,3/5,3/7,4/6,4/7}
        \draw (T\s) -- (T\t);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]