# Tikz : Creation of complex custom node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I've come again to pic your interesting brains.

I am trying to make a custom node with a drawing I've made

```
    \documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    
    \tikzset{
      pics/mynodeB/.style={
         code={
            \draw[fill] (0,0.5) circle (1cm);
            \draw[line width=4pt] (0,0) circle (2.2cm) ;
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\AngleA}{52.5}
            \draw[fill] (0,-2) arc (-90:-37.8:2cm) arc (29:66.2:1.8cm) arc (-\AngleA:{-180+\AngleA}:1.2cm)  arc ({180-66.2}:{180-29}:1.8cm) arc ({-180+37.8}:-90:2cm) ;
         }
      },
        cross/.style={path picture={
            \draw[black] let
              \p1 = (path picture bounding box.south),
              \p2 = (path picture bounding box.north),
              \n1 = {veclen((\x2-\x1),(\y2-\y1))}
              in ($(path picture bounding box.south east)!0.5!(path picture bounding box.north west)$) circle (1cm);  % Change is to be made here
        }},
    }
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
      \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[fill] (0,0.5) circle (1cm);
            \draw[line width=4pt] (0,0) circle (2.2cm) ;
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\AngleA}{52.5}
            \draw[fill] (0,-2) arc (-90:-37.8:2cm) arc (29:66.2:1.8cm) arc (-\AngleA:{-180+\AngleA}:1.2cm)  arc ({180-66.2}:{180-29}:1.8cm) arc ({-180+37.8}:-90:2cm) ;
            
          \pic[red] at (5,0) {mynodeB};
          \node[cross,minimum size=2cm] at (10,0) {};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}
```

It gives this

[image: User pictures]

The first is the drawing I'm trying to use. You can see some weird numerical values because I had drawn it using filled circles and some clipping/reversed clipping but it was not working well when I tried to turn it into a node so I approximated the shape with arcs.

The red one is the same drawing done with a "pic" I defined (I don't really know what a pic is, I used a code I found here...). The problem is that a pic is not a node, and I can't use my usual commands to play with it.

The circle on the right is based on a simpler custom node I had made previously. I am trying to make the same drawing than before, but I must not use fixed length (or the shape won't be resized with the node). You can see I have tried in `cross/.style` evaluating the length `\n1` of the node, but if I put `\n1` where `1cm` is, the circle disappears.

Do you have ideas ?

Comment: Good evening, I did not understand your problem.

Comment: I want to use the shape I've drawn as a node. You can criticize what I want to do, give me another way, or you can have an idea why the \n1 doesn't work.

Comment: If a pic is not a node, it is possible to create nodes in a pic and refer to them. So, depending on the use you will make of this pic, there is a solution to your problem. What will be the use of this pic?

Comment: It looks as if you like to make symbols for people. Do you know the relaxed TikZ- library for people? You may check on CTAN for tikzpeople.

Answer (score 7):

Quite hard to understand what you're looking for, but here's an attempt to answer. Pics are a way to *save* drawings and be able to reuse them. Hence, you can scale them too (like I did in violet).

A way to *name* a pic as a node is to give it the parameter `local bounding box=A`, for example. Then you can use `A` like a node, especially to place another one next to it, like I did (with the `positioning` library).

[image: pic as a node]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
   \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    
\tikzset{
      mypic/.pic={
            \filldraw (0,0.5) circle (1cm);
            \draw[line width=4pt] (0,0) circle (2.2cm) ;
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\AngleA}{52.5}
            \filldraw (0,-2) arc (-90:-37.8:2cm) arc (29:66.2:1.8cm) arc (-\AngleA:{-180+\AngleA}:1.2cm)  arc ({180-66.2}:{180-29}:1.8cm) arc ({-180+37.8}:-90:2cm) ;
      }
    }
   
    
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[on grid]
        \pic[red,local bounding box=A] {mypic};
        \pic[violet,scale=0.5,right=4 cm of A] {mypic};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try it out

Comment: +1 but quick question (not OP). What is the advantage of using `pic` instead if a macro that draws the image every time?

Answer (score 4):

You were almost there. You only need to introduce a scale factor that allows you to scale the pic without resorting to the `scale` key because otherwise you may be in trouble if you use the `scale` key on the node.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  pics/mynodeB/.style={
     code={
        \draw[fill] (0,0.5*#1) circle[radius=#1*1cm];
        \draw[line width=#1*4pt] (0,0) circle[radius=#1*2.2cm];
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\AngleA}{52.5}
        \draw[fill] (0,-2*#1) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=-37.8,radius=#1*2cm] 
         arc[start angle=29,end angle=66.2,radius=#1*1.8cm] 
         arc[start angle=-\AngleA,end angle={-180+\AngleA},radius=#1*1.2cm]  
         arc[start angle={180-66.2},end angle={180-29},radius=#1*1.8cm] 
         arc[start angle={-180+37.8},end angle=-90,radius=#1*2cm];
     }
  },pics/mynodeB/.default=1,
    cross/.style={circle,path picture={
        \path let
          \p1 = (path picture bounding box.south west),
          \p2 = (path picture bounding box.north east),
          \n1 = {scalar(veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)/4.4cm/sqrt(2))}
          in (path picture bounding box.center)
          pic{mynodeB=\n1};
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill] (0,0.5) circle (1cm);
    \draw[line width=4pt] (0,0) circle (2.2cm) ;
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\AngleA}{52.5}
    \draw[fill] (0,-2) arc (-90:-37.8:2cm) arc (29:66.2:1.8cm) arc (-\AngleA:{-180+\AngleA}:1.2cm)  arc ({180-66.2}:{180-29}:1.8cm) arc ({-180+37.8}:-90:2cm) ;
    \pic[red] at (5,0) {mynodeB};
    \node[cross,minimum size=2cm] (A) at (10,0) {};
    \node[cross,minimum size=2cm,blue] (B) at (14,0) {};
    \draw[thick,orange] (A.45) to[out=45,in=-135] (B.-135);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's simple and using a node.

Comment: Can you help me again, I've tried your solution, I'm quite happy with it, but there is something weird with `line width`, see for yourself the difference between `\draw pic{mynode};` and `\node[cross,minimum size=4.4cm] (C) at (5,0) {};`

Comment: Nodes seem to have a circle clip (1cm in diameter) on them

Comment: The `path picture` clips against the boundary path, which is a circle. If you choose `minimum size=2cm`, the radius is `1cm`, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Why not abuse a little bit from `path picture`? If the node is a `circle` with minimum size, it's possible measure this size and draw a figure proportional to it.

Following code need some adjustments, but it shows the idea

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
    
\tikzset{
    head/.style={circle, draw, path picture={%
        \fill let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north)-(path picture bounding box.south)$), \n1={veclen(\p1)} in ([yshift=.1*\n1]path picture bounding box.center) circle(0.22*\n1);
        \fill let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north)-(path picture bounding box.south)$), \n1={veclen(\p1)} in 
        ([shift={(45:.25*\n1)}]path picture bounding box.-135) to[out=-45, in=-135]
        ([shift={(135:.25*\n1)}]path picture bounding box.-45) to[bend right]
        ([shift={(135:.5*\n1)}]path picture bounding box.-45) to[out=-135, in=-45]
        ([shift={(45:.5*\n1)}]path picture bounding box.-135) to[bend right] cycle
        ;
    }}
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[head, minimum size=4cm, draw, blue, line width=1mm] (a) {};

\node[head, minimum size=2cm, draw, green, line width=1mm] at (4,0) (b) {};

\node[head, minimum size=1cm, draw, red] at (4,2) (b) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: Reduced code.

Previous code solution can be reduced with the help of [Mark Wibrow's "alias"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395641/1952) and compacting both `fill` commands into only one.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
    
\tikzset{
    alias path picture bounding box/.code=\pgfnodealias{#1}{path picture bounding box},
    head/.style={circle, draw, path picture={%
        \tikzset{alias path picture bounding box=@}
        \fill let \p1=($(@.north)-(@.south)$), \n1={veclen(\p1)} in ([yshift=.1*\n1]@.center) circle(0.22*\n1)%;
        ([shift={(45:.25*\n1)}]@.-135) to[out=-45, in=-135]
        ([shift={(135:.25*\n1)}]@.-45) to[bend right]
        ([shift={(135:.5*\n1)}]@.-45) to[out=-135, in=-45]
        ([shift={(45:.5*\n1)}]@.-135) to[bend right] cycle
        ;
    }}
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[head, minimum size=4cm, draw, blue, line width=1mm] (a) {};

\node[head, minimum size=2cm, draw, green, line width=1mm] at (4,0) (b) {};

\node[head, minimum size=1cm, draw, red] at (4,2) (b) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it removes the use of 'pic'.

Comment: When I play with that solution the drawback I have is the use of 'let', which you have to copy an paste for every command you use. That gives me some wet programming.

Comment: @LMT-PhD With the help of an `alias` for `pathpicture bounding box` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395641/1952) you can save some typing. And in this particular case, "head" and "body" can be drawn within one command which means only one `let` expression. See the updated code.