# How to proper resize blocks to fit text and reducing size of elements such as adder and mixer in Circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

Is there a proper way to change the size of an adder and a block in CircuiTikZ, in order to fit a transfer function inside a block?

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{ blocks/scale = 0.5}

\draw (0,0) node[adder] (m) {} 
(m.1) to[short,-o] ++(-1,0) node[](sp){}; 
 \draw (m.2) node[below left] {\scriptsize $-$};
 \draw (m.1) node[above left] {\scriptsize $+$};
  \draw(m.1) node[inputarrow] {}; 

\ctikzset{ blocks/scale = 1}
\draw (m.3) to[short,>] ++(0.5,0) to[amp, t=$K_c$,l_={\scriptsize Gain},>] ++(1.25,0) node[] (p){};
\ctikzset{ blocks/scale = 0.5}

\draw  (p) to[short,>] node[adder, fill=white] (int){} ++(0.75,0) (int.1) node[inputarrow] {};
\ctikzset{ blocks/scale = 1}

\draw (int.3) to[short] ++(2,0) node(ua) {} to[short] ++(0.25,0) to[twoport, l_={\scriptsize Process}, t=$\frac{k_p}{a s^2+b s+1}$,> ] ++(2.25,0) node(pv) {} to[short] ++(0,-2.25)  node (a){} to[short] (a -| m.2) to[short,>] (m.2)node[inputarrow,rotate=90]{};
\draw (pv) to[short,*-o] ++(0.5,0) node[] (pv2) {};

\draw (ua) to[short,*-] ++(0,-1) node[] (ua2){} to[twoport,l={\scriptsize Integral}, t=$\frac{1}{T_i s+1}$,>] ++(-2,0) node (uf){} to[short] (ua2 -| int.2) to[short,>] (int.2)node[inputarrow,rotate=90]{};
 \draw (int.2) node[below left] {\scriptsize $+$};
 \draw (int.1) node[above left] {\scriptsize $+$};
 \draw (ua)  node[above right]() {\scriptsize \quad $u$} (ua)  node[below right]() {\scriptsize\quad  MV};
 \draw (sp)  node[above](){\scriptsize $w$}  (sp)  node[below](){\scriptsize SP};
 \draw (pv2) node[above](){\scriptsize $y$}  (pv2) node[below](){\scriptsize PV};
 \draw (m.3) node[above right](){\scriptsize $e$};
 \draw (uf) node[above](){\scriptsize $u_f$}  (pv2);

\draw[dashed, cyan!70!black] (0.55,-2) rectangle ++(4.755,2.75);
\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Instead of code fragment always provide complete small document which can be compiled as it is. BTW, use of `circuitikz` for your block scheme is not the best tool. With pure TikZ you will have less problems.

Comment: I agree with @Zarko. Those blocks are better drawn as TikZ nodes (remember that you can freely mix `circuitikz` with them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pure `tikz`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                calc, 
                fit, 
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tikzset{
alias path picture bounding box/.code=%
    \pgfnodealias{#1}{path picture bounding box},
CNTRL/.style =
{
          > = Triangle,
block/.style = {rectangle, draw, 
    minimum height=8mm, minimum width=16mm,
    outer sep = 0mm},
  dot/.style = {fill,
    circle, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm, minimum size=1mm,
    node contents={}},
 gain/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, shape border rotate=-90, draw,
    inner sep=0pt, anchor=west,
    outer sep = 0mm},
sum/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=6mm,
    path picture={%
    \tikzset{alias path picture bounding box=@}
    \draw[very thick, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm, -]
    (@.north) edge (@.south)
    (@.west)   --  (@.east);
                },% end of node contents
            node contents={}},
}% end of CNTRL style
    }% end of tikzset

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[CNTRL, node distance = 5mm and 10mm]
\draw[{Circle[open]}->] (0,0) node[above] {$w$} 
                      node[below] {SP} -- ++ (1,0)  node[above left] {$+$}
                                                    node (s1) [sum,right];
\draw[->]   (s1.east) to["$e$"] ++ (1,0) node (g) [gain, right, 
                                                   label={[yshift=-3mm]below:Gain}] {$K_c$};
\draw[->]   (g.corner 1) -- ++ (1,0) node [above left] {$+$}
                                   node (s2) [sum,right];
\node (m1) [block, label={[name=int]below: Integral},
            below right=of s2] {$\dfrac{1}{T_i s +1}$};
\node (d1) [dot, right=of s2 -| m1.east]; 
\draw (s2) -- (d1); 
\draw (d1) to["$u$", "MW" '] ++ (1,0) node (m2) [block,right] {$\dfrac{k_p}{a s^2+b s+1}$};
\draw (m2.east) -- ++ (1,0) node (d2) [dot];
\draw[-{Circle[open]}]  (d2) -- ++ (1,0);
% inner loop
\draw[->]   (d1) |- (m1);
\draw[->]   (m1) -| (s2.south)  node[pos=0.25, above] {$u_f$}
                                node[below left] {$+$};
% outer loop
\coordinate[below=of int] (aux);
\draw[->]   (d2) |- (aux) -| (s1.south) node[below left] {$-$};
% fit
\node[draw=teal, dashed, inner sep=2mm, yshift=2mm, fit=(g) (d1) (int)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint with pure Tikz solution! My point, though, was to find out if the Circuitikz blocks class could have similar resizing of elements such a 'bipole/resistor/scale' and a block box with auto-resizing to fit text. The point of using the Circuitikz blocks instead of pure Tikz is to facilitate sharing the block diagram with a minimum code and keep some degree of compatibility.

Comment: @A.R.Braga, I disagree with your reasoning. In my answer is suggested (between other)  the set of styles  `CNTRL` dedicated to all similar sachems. It can be simple expand with more elements (for example see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395589/drawing-a-control-system-with-tikz/395620#395620), for which you will hard time to draw with `circuitikz`) and than relative simple draw even more complex controls' schemes. The pure `tikz` code for your scheme is simpler and more concise than with `circuitikz`. For electrical schemes the  `circuitikz` is superior, of course.

Comment: Wow, I've just reviewed your code suggestion and I agree 100% with you now. Actually you provided-me a very nice "small control block" solution, that can be expanded without packages! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can always restructure and scale things to fit ...

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{blocks/scale=0.5}
\draw (0,0) node[adder] (m) {} 
(m.1) to[short,-o] ++(-1,0) node[](sp){}; 
 \draw (m.2) node[below left] {\scriptsize $-$};
 \draw (m.1) node[above left] {\scriptsize $+$};
  \draw(m.1) node[inputarrow] {}; 

\ctikzset{ blocks/scale = 1}
\draw (m.3) to[short,>] ++(0.5,0) to[amp, t=$K_c$,l_={\scriptsize Gain},>] ++(1.25,0) node[] (p){};
\ctikzset{ blocks/scale = 0.5}

\draw  (p) to[short,>] node[adder, fill=white] (int){} ++(0.75,0) (int.1) node[inputarrow] {};
\ctikzset{ blocks/scale = 1}

\draw (int.3) to[short] ++(2,0) node(ua) {} to[short] ++(0.25,0) to[twoport, l_={\scriptsize Process}, 
t=\scalebox{0.5}{$k_p/(\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}a s^2\\
+b s\\
+1)\end{array}$},> ] ++(2.25,0) node(pv) {} to[short] ++(0,-2.25)  node (a){} to[short] (a -| m.2) to[short,>] (m.2)node[inputarrow,rotate=90]{};
\draw (pv) to[short,*-o] ++(0.5,0) node[] (pv2) {};

\draw (ua) to[short,*-] ++(0,-1) node[] (ua2){} to[twoport,l={\scriptsize Integral}, t=$\frac{1}{T_i s+1}$,>] ++(-2,0) node (uf){} to[short] (ua2 -| int.2) to[short,>] (int.2)node[inputarrow,rotate=90]{};
 \draw (int.2) node[below left] {\scriptsize $+$};
 \draw (int.1) node[above left] {\scriptsize $+$};
 \draw (ua)  node[above right]() {\scriptsize \quad $u$} (ua)  node[below right]() {\scriptsize\quad  MV};
 \draw (sp)  node[above](){\scriptsize $w$}  (sp)  node[below](){\scriptsize SP};
 \draw (pv2) node[above](){\scriptsize $y$}  (pv2) node[below](){\scriptsize PV};
 \draw (m.3) node[above right](){\scriptsize $e$};
 \draw (uf) node[above](){\scriptsize $u_f$}  (pv2);

\draw[dashed, cyan!70!black] (0.55,-2) rectangle ++(4.755,2.75);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

... but there is probably very little doubt that this is not pretty. So IMHO the real question is whether you really need to put such lengthy expressions in the elements of the circuit. Wouldn't it be better if you just put some well readable letters and use the text to explain what they mean?

Comment: Yes, we could use G(s), H(s) etc. However, for didactic purpose, inserting the full transfer function (up to a second order polynomial) helps understanding without further references to the block transfer function.

Comment: Many circuitikz components do not define the text anchor.  You would think a simple `\anchor{text} {\pgfpoint{-.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox}{-.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox}}` for every "hollow" node would be easy to add.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks! Please feel free to write an answer. The main point of this post is to talk the OP out of putting lengthy formula on the elements of the circuit.

Comment: I would have to fix the adder and amp shapes first.